# Why do some .obj files have no newlines?

Tags: c++, 3d-meshes, obj, model-loader

I'm working on a game engine and just started with mesh loading. I started with the format `.obj`. I ran into this problem:

The guide I'm following gave me a couple of `.obj` files to try and they all worked fine. I then asked a friend who is working with 3D animation to give me a couple of `.obj` files to try in addition, but his files, when opened up in a txt format, contain no newlines to separate the information at all. (Everything was on one line). The loading function I use depends on this to extract the information.

Are the files he gave me bad in some way? Is my function bad because it depends on newlines being there? (I can't see `.obj` files having any other delimiter character...)

My friend made and exported the 3D models in Blender. [This](http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=DX11Lessons) is the guide I'm following.

Comment: What OS does your friend use? Different operating systems use different newline characters, and it's possible that is causing the issue.

Comment: He is using windows 7, and so am I, but do you really think the blender export function should be affected by that :O ?

Comment: dunno, perhaps it uses system default filestream commands. whatever it doesn't matter now, thanks for crossing off that possibility

Comment: Windows version doesnt relly matter, locale can affect this too. But it highly probably that its caused by him exporting it with line breaks as \n and you are expecting \n\r.

Comment: Ok, but to the question at hand, is the file structur of .obj built so you seperate the information via  new lines or not :) ?

Comment: hmm interesting, when i copy some of the text in to another type of text format the new line appers, maby they are there but the txt format just dont register them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you opened the file in Notepad. Notepad doesn't recognize some new line formats.

The OBJ format does indeed use newlines as delimiters, and your files likely contain them. It's just not looking that way in Notepad. Try opening them in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) instead: I'll bet they'll appear correctly.

To make sure your parser function works correctly on all platforms, it should consider both `\n` (newline) and `\r` (carriage feed) characters as newlines.

Comment: The tutorial code probably assumes you are in the USA and using Windows.